# ENUM Session Attribute

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have a jsp and on page i have use session attribute. But key of session attribute in ENUM like this:

```
public Attribute{
    Attr1 ("project.part.subpart");
    private String attribute;
    private Attribute (String attribute)
    {
       this.attribute = attribute;
    }
}
```

How can I access to session attribute **NOT** like this:

```
request.getSession().getAttribute(Attribute.Attr1.toString());
```

Comment: Doesn't that somewhat defeat the point of using an enum in the first place?

Comment: @JonK I have alot session attribute, this is best way store this.

Comment: `How can I access to session attribute **NOT** like this:` what is meant by this ?

Comment: @NeerajJain this is not look well and cumbersome. I find another way get attribute